# C# - A simple way to call a method async?

Tags: events, user-interface, asynchronous

i am developing a c# user-control @ work. the control just loads some infos & data and displays it.

now i want to provide the user of the control with an option to load the data asynchron .. smth like this:

```
Cntrl.LoadSmthAsync(..)
Cntrl.LoadSmthComplete   //EventHandler to give feedback if the Load was successfull.
```

i decided to make the Download function Async and provide return values throu EventHandlers. 
 but that code got rather complicated .. after all.

here some code to understand what the control should do:

```
    public byte[] LoadByPos(int pos)
    {
        string url = Pos2Url(pos);

        // update gui
        this.textBox1.Text = url;

        byte[] res = LoadByUrl(url);

        // update gui
        this.textBox2.Text = BytesToString(res);

        return res;
    }

    public byte[] LoadByUrl(string url)
    {
        return Download(url);
    }

    //primary problem: download function
    private byte[] Download(string url)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 30);
        return StringToBytes(url);
    }

    //secondary problem: an other function
    private string Pos2Url(int pos)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 5);
        return pos.ToString();
    }




    // LoadByPosAsync
    public delegate void LoadByPosDoneHandler(Object sender, byte[] e);
    public event LoadByPosDoneHandler LoadByPosDone;

    public void LoadByPosAsync(int pos)
    {
        string url = Pos2Url(pos);

        // update gui
        this.textBox1.Text = url;

        LoadByUrlDone += new LoadByUrlDoneHandler(LoadByPosAsync_LoadByUrlDone);
        LoadByUrlAsync(url);
    }
    public void  LoadByPosAsync_LoadByUrlDone(object sender, byte[] e)
    {
        // update gui
        this.textBox2.Text = BytesToString(e);

        LoadByUrlDone = null;
        LoadByPosDone(sender, e);
    }


    //LoadByUrlAsync

    public delegate void LoadByUrlDoneHandler(Object sender, byte[] e);
    public event LoadByUrlDoneHandler LoadByUrlDone;

    public void LoadByUrlAsync(string url)
    {
        DownloadDone += new DownloadDoneHandler(LoadByUrlAsync_DownloadDone);
        DownloadAsync(url);
    }
    private void LoadByUrlAsync_DownloadDone(object sender, byte[] e)
    {
        LoadByUrlDone(sender, e);
    }

    //DownloadAsync

    private delegate void DownloadDoneHandler(Object sender, byte[] e);
    private event DownloadDoneHandler DownloadDone;

    private void DownloadAsync(string url)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw_DownloadAsync = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw_DownloadAsync.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_DownloadAsync_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw_DownloadAsync.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DownloadAsync_DoWork);
        bw_DownloadAsync.RunWorkerAsync(url);
    }
    void bw_DownloadAsync_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] res = Download((string)e.Argument);
        e.Result = res;
    }
    void bw_DownloadAsync_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadDone(sender, (byte[])e.Result);
    }
```

is there an easier way to accomplish what i am intending to do ?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easier way to accomplish what I am intending to do?

There's the *implementation* side separately, but if you're using .NET 4 I would *strongly* advise you not to use this model for asynchrony. Rather than using event handlers, I'd encourage you to use `Task<T>`. You can use [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) to create the task if you don't have any inherent support for it, and it means your API will be *much* easier to use in C# 5, due to the async/await support. At that point, your UI-thread method would look like this:

```
public async Task<byte[]> LoadByPos(int pos)
{
    string url = await Pos2UrlAsync(pos);

    // update gui
    this.textBox1.Text = url;

    byte[] res = await LoadByUrlAsync(url);

    // update gui
    this.textBox2.Text = BytesToString(res);

    return res;
}
```

The asynchrony will simply flow through your code naturally.

Comment: thx for your quick reply! i am currently kinda bound to .Net 2.0 cause the control may be used also in an older client application, that we cant port at the moment.

Comment: that code u posted looks soo sweet to my eyes .. 
but i dont know if i can use it in .net 2.0 ..
is .net 2.0 able to handle c# 5 ?

and thx for your help.

Comment: @nox: It's possible that with a lot of work and hackery you could get it to work, it's not really a sensible option.